# How to tune translog retention for small indices?

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently working on an ecommerce solution, we are using Elasticsearch 6.x to enable full-text search on products.

We have 88 indices, each one having a primary.store.size around 50mb. We have one replica for each primary. We are often regenerating those indices through bulk indexation with fixed _id. Because of that, translog is growing.

Each of my indices is pretty similar to these data provided through _cat/indices:

```
    index      pri rep docs.count  docs.deleted store.size  pri.store.size
    myindex_1   1   1     105533            0     79.4mb         39.7mb
```

For the same index, here are _cat/recovery data:

```
index    shard  time  type        stage snapshot files files_recovered files_percent files_total bytes   bytes_recovered bytes_percent bytes_total translog_ops translog_ops_recovered translog_ops_percent
myindex_1 0     14ms  empty_store done  n/a      0     0               0.0%          0           0       0               0.0%          0           0            0                      100.0%
myindex_1 0     22ms  peer        done  n/a      1     1               100.0%        1           233     233             100.0%        233         0            0                      100.0%
```

For the same index, here are _cat/shards data:

```
index      shard prirep state     docs  store 
myindex_1  0     p      STARTED 105533 39.7mb 
myindex_1  0     r      STARTED 105533 39.7mb
```

In its default configuration, translog retention size is 512mb and retention age is 12h. According to documentation, translog is now kept for a longer time to enable a faster shard recovery mechanism.

Given the size of our indices which is pretty small compared to the translog size, could I tweak safely the translog retention age or retention size? Or would I better increase my storage space to take into account the default translog properties ?

Comment: Can you provide more information related to your index size, number of shards and translog size? `GET _cat/indices?v` + `GET _cat/shards?v` + `GET _cat/recovery?v`

Comment: Hi, thank for your answer, I provided more information on our index data. Nevertheless, could we not abstract this "issue" of my server configuration? I would have loved to know if falling back to the previous recovery system could not be faster than using the one relying on undo/redo log given that index translog could be larger than my index size. I understand that using translog for very large indices is more performant, but for my use cases I don't really know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The retention settings control how much of the translog file and for how long should be kept in order to refresh the offline replicas during recovery.

The more information you keep in translog files the better chance to succeed in recovery, but big files will require more server resources and their processing will take longer. So, you have to keep a good balance here.

The default setting at 512 MB for the retention size is not enough if you experience a high throughput workload, so you can safely increase it say up to 1024 MB. The retention age can also be altered and, potentially, will lead you to increase your disk storage, so once updated both settings, please keep an eye on the available disk space and, depending on the demand, plan the required disk storage upgrade.

Comment: Thank for answer. Nevertheless, according to an article https://www.elastic.co/fr/blog/elasticsearch-sequence-ids-6-0, if I am not wrong with version prior to 6.x, Elasticsearch shard recovery mecanism were relying on lucene segment copies. With version 6.x, if translog is too old we should fall back on that strategy. Given that index stored size is very small in front of translog size, may I take the risk to altered retention size as I know that copying Lucene segment should be fast (maybe faster than using a very large translog ).

Comment: File copying is an expensive operation usually and you can find out which way is faster only by testing both recovering approaches: translog vs. old file-based technique. Just try to simulate a failure when you have quite a big translog and then recover your failed replica in 2 ways. Next you can easily measure the efforts you spent and make the final decision re replication approach. I vote for the fast recovery by translog, unless you experience a hardware crash.